# Using muffin/cupcake pan for basque burnt cheesecake

Tags: baking, equipment, pan, cheesecake

I've seen images of regular cheesecake (crust + filling) baked in muffin tins,

[image]

Will basque burnt cheesecake be as creamy as the original in muffin/cupcake pan?

Here's the pan I'd like to use, each tin around 7.5 cm/3 inch:
[image]

Comment: That is a good question. As someone that is looking into making basque cheesecake AND never thought of using the muffin pan for this, I'm looking forward to the answers!

Answer (score 2):

I expect that you will need to change the baking temperature or (mostly) the cooking time.

The smaller muffin pans have a large surface area so the heat will penetrate quicker and cook your cheesecake quicker.

I suggest you experiment, check to see if there are cheesecake recipes that use muffin pans to have an idea about cooking time and temperature.